# Is there a way to set non-secret environment variables in Github Actions on the Settings page?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

As far as I know, there are two ways to set environment variables in Github Actions:

- Hardcoding them into YAML file
- Adding them as repository secrets on the settings page

[Repository secrets page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAm8V.png)

But what if I don't want them to be secret? On the picture above, SERVER_PREFIX and ANALYTICS_ENABLED shouldn't be secret. Is there a way to set up env variables on the settings page and make them visible? In Travis we had that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In January 2023, GitHub added support for non-secret configuration variables ([blog post](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-01-10-github-actions-support-for-configuration-variables-in-workflows/)):

[image: GitHub Actions variables tab]

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an option to add non-secret ENV variables on GitHub page at now.

You can create workflow-scope ENV variables in workflow step.

```
env:
   SERVER_PREFIX: SOME_PREFIX
```

Then access by:
`${{ env.SERVER_PREFIX }}`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use them in the Action's YAML, just define your variables in a downloadable file and then use something like curl or wget to get them into your build environment.

For instance, I've done something similar for [common CI files](https://www.slideshare.net/mbrandizi/continuos-integration-knetminer) and now I've multiple projects running the same project building scripts, their local action is simply like: download an .sh file, run it.

If you need to set up variables in one of your build steps, to be used later by some other action, [have a look at this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files) (but I've never tried it myself).